# Regex get stripped(1 vowel, 1 constant) words from a string

Tags: python, regex

note: I'm getting into regex and I know regex isn't best solution in this case, but I'm still interested how and if it would be possible.

The task:

> You are given a block of text with different words. These words are
>   separated by white-spaces and punctuation marks. Numbers are not
>   considered words in this mission (a mix of letters and digits is not a
>   word either). You should count the number of words (striped words)
>   where the vowels with consonants are alternating, that is; words that
>   you count cannot have two consecutive vowels or consonants. The words
>   consisting of a single letter are not striped -- do not count those.
>   Casing is not significant for this mission.
>
> Input: A text as a string (unicode)
>
> Output: A quantity of striped words as an integer.

example:
string1 = "Dog,cat,mouse,bird.Human." should return 3.

Comment: Could be, could be not, can't say for sure.

Comment: so far the only solution where I could use regex is going through each string and checking every character, but then the is no point to use regex aside from vanity

Comment: This question needs no more information. Whoever voted to put this on hold can not possibly have actually read the question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think there're two main ways of doing that, first to check that vowels and consonants alternate.

For instance, to check that `a` and `b` alternate, you would use something like this:

```
a(?:ba)+|b(?:ab)+
```

Extending this to vowels/consonants, you can get this rather long regex:

```
(?<![a-z])(?:[aeiou](?:[^P{L}aeiou][aeiou])+|[^\P{L}aeiou](?:[aeiou][^\P{L}aeiou])+)(?![a-z])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS3sA0)

The two negative lookarounds `(?<![a-z])` and `(?![a-z])` act as word boundaries and ensure that the whole word is checked.

`[aeiou]` is for vowels and `[^P{L}aeiou]` for consonants. It's the equivalent of `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`

The second way is to ensure there's no consecutive vowel or consonant in the word. And this one requires another negative lookahead, but is a little shorter:

```
(?<![a-z])(?:(?![aeiou]{2}|[^\P{L}aeiou]{2})[a-z])+(?![a-z])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/rR3rO9)

You can use `re.findall` with `re.I` active (or use `(?i)` at the start of the regex) to get all the matches, then get the length of the list to get the count of 'striped words'.

```
(?<![a-z])              # Ensure no letter before
  (?:
    (?!
      [aeiou]{2}        # Ensure no two consecutive vowel
    |
      [^\P{L}aeiou]{2}  # Ensure no two consecutive consonant
    )
    [a-z]               # Any letter
  )+
(?![a-z])               # Ensure no more letters
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot, still it's pretty hard to bend my mind around some of the regex stuff.

Comment: @Granitas No problem! And don't need to rush it. Regex can take some time to get used to, and I can tell you that lookarounds is a chapter I consider to be moderately advanced, so it's okay if you don't understanding it immediately. There're quite a few regex tutorials online which I believe can help you through if you want to learn regex.